# Timezone setting in Jquery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, timezone, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery UI date picker.The user have to enter booking in date and booking out date and on the basis of these dates booking days are calculated.I have to set the timezone of UK in order to calculate booking days.How can i do this?
As without setting the timezone the difference calculated between two dates is not correct.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript date object includes `getTimezoneOffset()` method based on user's machine settings and compared to GMT. I don't understand enough of how you need to use this in your application to guide any further

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset